# Can a network of nodes (graph) be represented as one or more trees?

Tags: graph, tree

When I convert my graph into trees I don't mind having duplicate nodes in the trees.  let me explain the reverse way.  Suppose I have 2 trees with a common element.  I can join them on the common element to create a graph.

Can I do this in the opposite direction, i.e., start with the graph and split an element into duplicates to create multiple trees?

Comment: Wouldn't be the *one tree for any edge* solution (as an extreme case) a solution as-is?

Comment: that seems correct.  However, I want as few trees as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want a tree containing all the links from the original, by allowing original nodes to appear several times in this tree. It's some kind of [spanning tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_tree), except the constraint is on keeping all links (instead of keeping all nodes, as in a classic spanning tree).

So you can use a similar approach than those used for discovering classic spanning trees. The basic approach is based on either breadth- or depth-first search. You start from a random node, and you add it to your tree. You then explore its neighbors using the search algorithm, and each time you reach a node, you add it to your tree (with the corresponding link). You must maintain a list of all processed links, so that you don't end up treating the same link twice. Also, you need a way to identify each node uniquely, to allow subsequent processing on your tree. For instance, simply number the nodes in your original graph.